# mxmlc outputs Russian symbols

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I've downloaded flex SDK from adobe.com. When I call mxmlc or compc russian symbols are outputed, so it's impossible to work in command line. Is it possible somehow to switch language to English?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you're using Windows: 
Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Regional Options, set English as your system language. This should help.